# Transfer using cli and choosing lowest fee?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, transaction-fees, transfer

How do you write the command to set the lowest fee during a transfer with the monero cli?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to understand priority levels using the transfer command. Read: [What does the "default" priority (priority = 0) do in monero-wallet-cli?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/4544/what-does-the-default-priority-priority-0-do-in-monero-wallet-cli)

There are 4 levels:

First note that the priority levels unimportant, normal, elevated, and priority correspond to multipliers of x1, x4, x20, and x166, respectively.

To send with lowest you would do:

```
transfer unimportant <address> <amount>
```

Example output:

```
[wallet 46xxxx]: transfer unimportant 4BSX2Par....LU2T6xxx 2 

There is currently a 1 block backlog at that fee level. Is this okay?  (Y/Yes/N/No)Y
Sending 2.000000000000.  The transaction fee is 0.003088120000
Is this okay?  (Y/Yes/N/No): Y
Transaction successfully submitted, transaction <xx9xcvd3434...3243>
You can check its status by using the `show_transfers` command.
[wallet 46hxxxx]:
```