# What are the standard fee multiplier levels?

Tags: transaction-fees

In the GUI wallet the fees are written as

- Slow: x0.25
- Normal: x1
- Fast: x5
- Fastest: x41.5

But I just made two transactions with slow and normal fee respectively and the slow fee was 1/5 of the normal fee. Does anyone know the real levels?

Comment: Can you confirm that your transactions were identical in terms of the number of inputs and number of outputs?

Comment: Yes, they are otherwise identical.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't speak to why the GUI has them labeled that way, but the current, *actual* fee multipliers are:

`1, 5, 25, 1000` [[ref]](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/bf525793c724f62d4716aaca59345ba2e13a2c3c/src/wallet/wallet2.cpp#L6961).

What confuses this a little further though is that the *default* strategy is to use auto-low fees. The default/automatic multiplier that gets used is 5, which potentially gets adjusted down to 1 (based on network/chain conditions) [[ref]](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/bf525793c724f62d4716aaca59345ba2e13a2c3c/src/wallet/wallet2.cpp#L7084) [[ref]](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/bf525793c724f62d4716aaca59345ba2e13a2c3c/src/wallet/wallet2.cpp#L6973).

Armed with this information and reviewing the source code, selecting "Normal" eventually ends up with a multiplier of 5 and selecting "Slow" ends up with a multiplier of 1, which explains your 1/5 observation. If you selected "Automatic" in the GUI, you'd be using a multiplier of 5, which may get adjusted down to 1.

As the labels in the GUI are scaled to the "Normal" being x1, they should probably read x0.2, x1, x5 and x200 respectively, slow to fastest.

Comment: So this means when the GUI wallet is set to "Automatic" it picks a fee that is x5 the lowest fee even when there is no need for it?

Comment: No, it means Automatic *starts* at the same as Normal and gets further adjusted. If it can safely go lower, it gets reduced to Slow.

Comment: @PyrolitePancake - As far as I know, Automatic will use the lowest multiplier if network traffic is sufficiently low. It will switch to the normal multiplier if network traffic passes a certain threshold. This was implemented to improve user experience.

Comment: Automatic goes like this: If there's a backlog in tx pool, use Normal (5). If the last 10 blocks on chain use up 80% or more of the full reward zone, use Normal (5). Otherwise use Slow (1). This is because `adjust_priority` when called with priority 0 (auto), either keeps priority at 0 or changes to 1. Then when `get_fee_multiplier` is called, if priority is still 0, it will use the Normal multiplier. Otherwise Slow gets used.